# Concatenation of two radical ideals is radical

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $I = (f_1,f_2,\cdots, f_k) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m]$ and $J = (g_1,g_2,\cdots, g_r) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[y_1,y_2,\cdots, y_n]$ be radical ideals (we know that the $f_i$ and $g_j$ exist because $\mathbb{C}$ ring-adjoin any number of variables is Noetherian). Their *concatenation* is defined to be the ideal $$(f_1,f_2,\cdots, f_k, g_1,g_2,\cdots, g_r) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m, y_1,y_2,\cdots, y_n].$$ Is it possible that this concatenated ideal is not radical in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m, y_1,y_2,\cdots, y_n]$?

Comment: What if $m=n=1$?

Comment: See for example Tag [00I4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I4).

Comment: ah, so no counterexamples exist and the concatenated ideal is always radical?

Comment: @atenao Yes, that follows.